# How to extract only certain data from a collection with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection with only a `name` and a `number`. I would like to extract only the number out of it and change it / put it in a variable. How would I do either of those?

```
    let dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    views: Number
})

   let Views = mongoose.model("View", dataSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a [second argument](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) to the find() method indicating the fields that must be returned.

```js
Views.findOne({}, { views: true }, (err, doc) => {
  if (!err) {
    // doc.views
  }
});
```

## Edit

---

There are several other options for limiting the returned fields with mongoose

#### Option 2

Pass space-separated field names:

```js
Views.findOne(query, "views", callback)
```

#### Option 3

Using `select()` method:

```js
Views.findOne(query).select('views').exec(callback);
```

```js
Views.findOne(query).select({ views: 1 }).exec(callback);
```

Comment: works the same as the old one did, when I console.log the variable it returns the entire object and not just the views property...

Comment: @icyfox I've added two new options to the answer you can try